# Giving Animation in AR

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, ar.js

I want to give animation in AR using A-Frame. I did like this.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-
ar.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
<a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-sphere ball1 id="ball1" class="clickable" position="-1 0.5 0" material="color: red;" scale="1 1 1">
            <a-animation attribute="position" 
             from="-1 0.5 0"
             to="-1 0 0"
             dur="500"
             begin="bounce-start"
             end="bounce-stop"
             fill="backwards"
             easing="ease-in"
             repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-sphere>
        <a-sphere ball2 id="ball2" class="clickable" position="2 0.5 0" material="color: green;" scale="1 1 1">
            <a-animation attribute="position" 
             from="2 0.5 0"
             to="2 0 0"
             dur="500"
             begin="bounce-start"
             end="bounce-stop"
             fill="backwards"
             easing="ease-in"
             repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-sphere>
</a-marker>
<a-camera position="0.5 0 0">
    <a-cursor id="cursor"
            raycaster="objects: .clickable" 
            fuse-timeout="2000"
            material="color: #F4D03F; shader: flat" 
            opacity="0.9">
    <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="150" fill="forwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="1500" fill="backwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
  </a-cursor>
</a-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code. Here is my JavaScript code.

```
var bouncing = false;
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
 bouncing = !bouncing;
 var el = document.querySelector("#ball1");
 el.emit(bouncing ? 'bounce-start' : 'bounce-stop');
 var el2 = document.querySelector("#ball2");
 el2.emit(bouncing ? 'bounce-start' : 'bounce-stop');
});
```

But nothing is happening after clicking the balls. why is that? But it works without AR. Can't I put animation in AR?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with click - detection, not with animations, multiple github issues, like [here](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/231), [here](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/249), or [here](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/237) show, that the cursor is not working properly.
From what i see people made workarounds by :

1. getting rid of the `look-controls` and `fuse`, or
2. listening for clicks on the entire window.